# Can only target Bosh Lite Director. Please use 'bosh target' before running this script

Tags: cloud-foundry, cf-bosh

I installed Cloud Foundry using bosh/microbosh. Now I am trying to install [Cloud Foundry Admin UI](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/admin-ui) using the [admin-ui-boshrelease](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/admin-ui-boshrelease#bosh-release-for-cloudfoundry-ng-admin-ui)

While running `./make_manifest warden`, I am getting error:

```
Can only target Bosh Lite Director. Please use 'bosh target' before running this script.
```

I have set the target to 192.168.0.5:

```
$ bosh target
Current target is https://192.168.0.5:25555 (vms-dev2)
```

I opened `make_manifest` file and found it supports aws, vsphere and warden.  In case of warden it looks for the director name to be "Bosh Lite Director". In my case by is bosh director's name is "vms-dev2".

I installed Cloud Foundry using BOSH not BOSH-Lite. Is this Cloud Foundry Admin UI release supported in BOSH-Lite only, not with BOSH?

Comment: If you did not use BOSH-Lite, then do not use `./make_manifest warden`. If you deployed using BOSH to AWS, then use `./make_manifest aws`. If you deployed using BOSH to vSphere, then use `./make_manifest vsphere`. If you deployed to a different IaaS, like OpenStack, you may have to construct your manifest manually.  You can open an issue on the GitHub repo, the maintainer should be able to guide you with creating a manifest.

Comment: Thanks @AmitKumarGupta .Yes I need to create manifest (.yml) for admin ui.

Answer (score 0):

I created deployment file and it worked fine for me.

```
<%
load '/opt/installer/tenant-devtest1/cf-deploy/cf-settings.rb'
%>
name: <%= $deployment_name %>

director_uuid: 0de3e7b2-4e02-4149-bb79-980c1fe19f74

releases:
- {name: admin-ui, version: 6}

networks:
- name: ccc-bosh-net1
  type: dynamic
  cloud_properties:
    net_id: <%= $bosh_net_id %>
    security_groups:
        - cfoundry
        - bosh
        - default

resource_pools:
  - name: small
    network: ccc-bosh-net1
    stemcell:
      name: bosh-openstack-kvm-ubuntu-trusty-go_agent-raw
      version: <%= $stemcell_version %>
    cloud_properties:
      instance_type: Micro-Small

compilation:
  workers: 2
  network: ccc-bosh-net1
  cloud_properties:
    instance_type: Micro-Small

update:
  canaries: 0
  canary_watch_time: 30000-600000
  update_watch_time: 30000-600000
  max_in_flight: 4
  serial: true

jobs:
- name: admin_ui
  template: admin_ui
  instances: 1
  resource_pool: small
  persistent_disk: 5120
  networks:
    - name: ccc-bosh-net1

- name: register_admin_ui
  template: register_admin_ui
  instances: 1
  resource_pool: small
  lifecycle: errand
  networks:
    - name: ccc-bosh-net1

- name: deregister_admin_ui
  template: deregister_admin_ui
  instances: 1
  resource_pool: small
  lifecycle: errand
  networks:
    - name: ccc-bosh-net1

properties:
  cc:
    srv_api_uri: <%= $protocol %>://api.<%= $root_domain %>
  system_domain: <%= $root_domain %>
  uaa:
    url: <%= $protocol %>://uaa.<%= $root_domain %>
    admin:
      client_secret: <%= $common_password %>
  admin_ui:
    cloud_controller_uri: <%= $protocol %>://api.<%= $root_domain %>
    cloud_controller_ssl_verify_none: true
    uri: <%= $protocol %>://admin.<%= $root_domain %>
    users: ~
    uaa:
      url: <%= $protocol %>://uaa.<%= $root_domain %>
      admin_client_secret: <%= $common_password %>
      client:
        id: admin_ui_client
        secret: <%= $common_password %>
      scopes:
        admin: ~
        user: ~

    ccdb:
      scheme: postgres
      address: 0.cloud-controller.ccc-bosh-net.<%= $deployment_name %>.microbosh
      port: 5524
      username: ccadmin
      password: <%= $common_password %>
      database: ccdb
    uaadb:
      scheme: postgresql
      address: 0.cloud-controller.ccc-bosh-net.<%= $deployment_name %>.microbosh
      port: 5524
      username: uaaadmin
      password: <%= $common_password %>
      database: uaadb

  ssl:
    skip_cert_verify: true
  networks:
    apps: ccc-bosh-net1

  nats:
    user: nats
    password: <%= $common_password %>
    address: 0.cloud-controller.ccc-bosh-net.<%= $deployment_name %>.microbosh
    port: 4222
```